# agglomerative clustering java

Tags: java, cluster-analysis

Is there any java file that I can use to perform "agglomerative clustering"
Result should provide me every level nodes id 
help.................

Comment: No it is not homework from any school. But you can say my own created work :). I am jumping into java world !

Comment: Why not start with implementing "agglomerative clustering"? It's not hard to implement, at least the naive `O(n^3)` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)'s [`HierarchicalClusterer`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/HierarchicalClusterer.html) class?

In any case, the [agglomerative hierarchical clustering algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Agglomerative_hierarchical_clustering) is fairly straightforward, assuming you have a function that yields the distance value between two clusters.

For a standard example, [Kruskal's minimum spanning tree algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) proceeds by clustering nearby nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The S-Space Package has a [HierarchicalAgglomerativeClustering](http://code.google.com/p/airhead-research/source/browse/trunk/sspace/src/edu/ucla/sspace/clustering/HierarchicalAgglomerativeClustering.java) class that returns the full dendrogram as the series of merge operations.  I believe this will give you the level information you want.  As a bonus, there's also a multi-threaded version too.